# Android provider path for camera and security

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I followed [this article](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en) to take picture in my application, however in the article the author gives the path `.` for the FileProvider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

To what corresponds exactly `.` and can it be a security issue?

Comment: To `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. What kind of security issue are you thinking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To what corresponds exactly `.`

It refers to the directory identified by your element. In [the case of `<external-path>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles), that is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

If, instead of `.`, you had `foo`, that would point to a `foo/` subdirectory under the directory identified by your element.

> can it be a security issue?

Only if you do something really strange in your Java code.

A `FileProvider` cannot be exported. The only things that can access content served by that provider are:

- Your app
- Any apps to which you grant permission from the Java code in your app

Typically, you grant permission via `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` and/or `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION` on an `Intent`. This grants read or write access to the one app that processes the `Intent` for the `Uri` that is inside that `Intent`. This is a very limited permission grant, and it is necessary for you to successfully use the `FileProvider`.

If you find yourself granting permissions in other ways, to more apps and for more content, then perhaps there is a security issue. But, again, it is tied to your Java code, not so much the `FileProvider` metadata.